# Uniquely describing a polytopal complex by prescribing the local structure around its vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, simplicial-complexes, polytopes, abstract-polytopes

Let $C$ be a $d$-dimensional *(abstract) polytopal complex*.
Most of what I say below could be asked in this general setting, but for a start, let's further restrict to *simple polytopal spheres*, that is, $C$ is homeomorphic to the $d$-sphere, and at each vertex meet exactly $d+1$ facets.

My goal is to formalize and then prove a certain kind of statement.
For a warmup, here are two examples of what I am after:

- Assume that each vertex of $C$ is incident to $d+1$ facets, each one combinatorially equivalent to the $d$-cube. From that I can already deduce that $C$ is combinatorially equivalent to the (boundary of the) $(d+1)$-cube.
- Assume that $d=2$ and each vertex is incident to a 4-gonal cell and two 6-gonal cells. This already suffices to conclude that $C$ is combinatorially equivalent to the (boundary of the) [permutahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).

In general, I want to prove something like this:

> If each vertex of a simple polytopal sphere $C$ looks the same locally (that is, is incident to the same type of facets), then $C$ is already uniquely determined.

So how to prove this?

Intuitively, this is easy.
Take, for example, the second example from above (and see the image below): if you try to draw its edge graph, you will start with a single vertex (the white dot) surrounded by a 4-gon and two 6-gons. You then see that there are several vertices for which only a single face is missing (the black dots), and you add these. 
You go on until you realize that now all the vertices satisfy the constraint.
You never made a choice, and so the result must be unique.

[image]

My question is the following:

> **Question:** How can this proof be formalized?

There seem to be some subtleties, some are hinting at certain generalizations:

- You need to use that $C$ is a polytopal *sphere*, otherwise the complex might not be unique.
  For example, there are infinitely many possibilities to realize a polytopal *torus* in which every vertex is incident to exactly three 6-gons. Maybe "sphere" can be replaced by *simply connected*, though.
- We do not necessarily need *simple*, but it is the "simplest" of several conditions that ensure that we never have to make a choice when placing the next facet. Here is a case where above reasoning fails because we dropped simplicity: if we want every vertex of a 2-dimensional complex to be surrounded by a 3-gon and three 4-gons, there are two solutions: [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicuboctahedron) and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_square_gyrobicupola).
- How do I know that there is always a vertex at which the next facet is determined?
- How can one be sure that the order in which I add new facets (which are forced on me) does not make a difference. Or does it?

Comment: Re: the last question - "How can one be sure that the order in which I add new facets (which are forced on me) does not make a difference. Or does it?" - since a facet can never stop being forced once it is forced, I think a routine application of the 'diamond lemma' proves confluence, i.e., that it does not matter which order you carry out the forced facet additions.

Comment: @SamHopkins This was already a very helpful hint. I wasn't aware of this lemma. Just a note: one might want to apply above reasoning to tilings of $\Bbb R^n$ too. In that case, the process of adding further facets isn't finite. If I understood correctly, this finiteness is an important condition in the diamond lemma. Is there away around this?

Comment: In general there is no way around some kind of finiteness condition to apply the diamond lemma.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but there are counterexamples to your local to global quest:

Consider the [uniform small rhombicuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicuboctahedron) versus the [elongated square gyrobicupola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_square_gyrobicupola) (Miller's solid, one of the Johnson solids). - Both show up the same vertex figures all over, still they are globally different (i.e. non-unique) outcomes (polyhedra).

--- rk

Comment: This counterexample is already contained in my post in the third to last bullet point. This is why I need the rule for adding one more tile that the placement must be unique, as it is in the simple case.

Comment: Just want to let you know that similar finds to Miller's solid lately were found within 4D, cf. http://www.polytope.net/hedrondude/polychora.htm#pseudouniform